# Density of states - interpreting graph

Tags: density-of-states

I am trying to correctly wrap my head around the density of states concept, wonder if anyone can help....

When looking at the classical graph that is used to describe this concept, we have density of states on the y axis and energy on the x-axis. I understand that if you integrate under a curve between two points you can find out the number of energy states of a system between those two points/energies. However, my question is whether or not the 'density of states' shown on this y-axis is a cumulative value? For example, if you read off the d.o.s value at some point on the x-axis (let's say x1), (as I understand it) we would get some value which would be the number of states at that energy (let's say y1)....but does y1 include all of the states between x=0 and x1? Or is it to say there are y1 states at that energy value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- The *density of states (DOS)* is a derivative of the *number of states* - the latter being the total number of states with energy less than x.
- DOS largely behaves as a probability density for a continuous probability distribution - it doesn't make sense to talk about the density at a specific value, but only about the number of states between two values.
- DOS is particularly useful when calculating the total number of occupied states, which gives the particle concentration:
  $$n =\int dE DOS(E) f(E),$$
  Where $f(E)$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution function.